# processmaker : connect to database

Tags: database

according to the title, i want to connect the process maker to the database.

i use MySql as an engine, the server is localhost, and the port is 3306. after submit the configuration, then the processmaker doing 4 steps to test the connection. i already passed the first 2 step, but the 3 and 4 step are failed.
the processmaker say :

> MySql connection refused!

i follow the instruction from http://wiki.processmaker.com/index.php/Database_Connections
but it still doesn't work.

thanks for your answer

Comment: You say _"i follow[ed] the instruction from ..."_ but unless you tell us what you actually did, it's going to be very difficult for anybody to help you.

Comment: Make sure your database username is correct. For example, my MySQL username is "root".

Answer (score 0):

Did you verify that your information is the correct one???

Check your mysql Username and password, and try using 127.0.0.1 as server

Answer (score 0):

When you installed ProcessMaker, which database did you use as a default one?, I've asked you this beacuse ProcessMaker comes with Apache and Mysql by default so maybe this step is unuseful to do.

Regards,

[processmaker](/questions/tagged/processmaker)

Answer (score 0):

make sure you are using correct version of mysql supported by processmaker.